# OpenCV 1.1 Error Mac OS X 10.5.7 "couldn't create video channel"

Tags: macos, opencv, quicktime

Application works on Unix but is getting an internal error from OpenCV on Mac OS X.  The rest of the programs seem to work.  Seems to be related to quicktime.

```
OpenCV Error: Internal error (couldnt create new video channel) in icvOpenCamera_QT, file /opencv/opencv/src/highgui/cvcap_qt.cpp, line 921
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

Haven't tried recompiling with ffmpeg, I have the components installed but don't know how ffmpeg works with live camera support on OS X.  Any suggestions as to the error or a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

hey there, i just ran into this problem and solved it with alot of frustration.

what i needed to do was to download the newer "OpenCV-Private-Framework-1.2.dmg"
file and drag the opencv folder into a folder named Library inside my app folder,
after this you will get an error about a haar... file, go into the provided face detection 
folder, copy all the haar files and add these directly to your apps folder (eg. sketches/face_detection).

so far i can only get this to work with an exported app; i am currently working on getting the .pde to work with this same library.
if you figure it out let me know.

oh, also, if you have troubles with it accessing the webcams, you have to open the apps contents and sign the java files using xcode which can be found within: contents/resources/java

search processing on how to sign an app, its fairly straightforward
so yeh, good luck and let me know if you can get the sketchbook .pde files to run

=)